# Microsoft Graph Api - Filtering users based on group membership

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The problem i'm trying to solve is fetching group membership of all users that belong to a root group.
I have made these two attempts (code below), but neither work

```cs
// using Microsoft.Graph nuget package
var test1 = await graphClient.Users.Request()
    .Filter($"memberOf/any(c:c, id eq 'root-group-id')") // this filter seems to be invalid
    //.Filter($"memberOf/any(c:c/id eq 'root-group-id')") // and this doesn't seem to work either
    .Expand("memberOf")
    .Select(x => x.Id)
    .GetAsync();

var test2 = await graphClient.Groups["root-group-id"].Members.Request()
    .Expand("memberOf")
    .GetAsync();
```

Does anybody have any alternative approaches on how to solve this without querying all users?

Comment: Try something like this `var test2 = await graphClient.Groups["root-group-id"].Request()
    .Expand("memberOf")
    .GetAsync();`

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma, yes that executes but that returns the root group's `memberOf` which is not what I'm after. I want to find all members (users) of that group and i want to find which groups they belong to.

Comment: Then as per my knowledge with only single HTTP call its not possible. You need to make other calls by using a foreach loop for each user you get from the above memberOf code. This is the other call which I am telling you `var memberOf = await graphClient.Users["each-user-id"].MemberOf
 .Request()
 .GetAsync();`

Comment: Yes, i understand that is an option but i would prefer to find a faster solution as firing off a lot of requests will be slow operation

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time on this. I agree with Shiva, single HTTP call may not work. How ever you can rely on task parallelism and Asynchrony to fetch you quicker and interactive output. I would use Parallel.Foreach loop for the above mentioned call.